# Xubuntu 14.04 Eclipse Crash with no reason

Tags: ubuntu, crash, eclipse, xubuntu, pdt

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. Eclipse 3.8 crashing with no reason. Suddenly closed. I have no idea why. Nothing special in the .log file.

I am using Oracle Java 1.8.

I am using Eclipse 3.8

I use PDT for PHP programming.

Here is the log:

```
xxx@dellorian:~/workspace/.metadata$ tail -n50 .log
!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-06-26 18:49:31.046
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-06-26 18:49:31.046
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+I:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+I,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.commands.Inspect,Inspect,
        Inspect result of evaluating selected text,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+I,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.php.debug.ui.commands.Inspect,Inspect,
        Inspect result of evaluating selected text,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
!SESSION 2014-06-26 19:35:35.152 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=debbuild
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-06-26 19:35:38.100
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-06-26 19:35:45.963
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2014-06-26 19:35:45.963
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+SHIFT+I:
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+I,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui.commands.Inspect,Inspect,
        Inspect result of evaluating selected text,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+SHIFT+I,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.php.debug.ui.commands.Inspect,Inspect,
        Inspect result of evaluating selected text,
        Category(org.eclipse.debug.ui.category.run,Run/Debug,Run/Debug command category,true),
        ,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
xxx@dellorian:~/workspace/.metadata$
```

This is really weird ...

Comment: Perhaps this article will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522606/no-auto-completion-on-eclipse-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-14-04